# Ruby regex to match all subdomains for my website?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm new to using regex expressions.  I need to accept all subdomains like:

```
something.mysite.com
something2.mysite.com
anotherthing.mysite.com
```

What kind of regex can I put there if I want to do something like:

```
rack_env['SERVER_NAME'].match <regex>
```

Comment: There is no need for a regular expression. A string match will tell you if it's a subdomain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a regex here. The way to go is:

```
rack_env['SERVER_NAME'].end_with?(".mysite.com")
```

Comment: will that math mysite.com ?

Comment: `"will that math mysite.com ?"` Did you try it?

Comment: Im on it. But I need to negate that condition, an unless doesnt work! @theTinMan

Comment: Use `rack_env['SERVER_NAME'] == 'mysite.com' || rack_env['SERVER_NAME'].end_with?(".mysite.com")`. That looks for the main sitename match, and, if that fails, looks for sub-domains.

Comment: how can I ask if the server name doent match 'mysite.com' and doesnt end with '.mysite.com' ??? @theTinMan

Comment: Use `!(rack_env['SERVER_NAME'] == 'mysite.com' || rack_env['SERVER_NAME'].end_with?(".mysite.com"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of `\.mysite\.com$` should work. http://rubular.com is a good resource for testing regular expressions.

Comment: You forgot to escape dots. I would give even `.+\.mysite\.com$`, that there can be dots and other stuff in subdomain.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to escape the . in .com.

Comment: In that case you'd just leave off the opening . and use `/mysite\.com$/`

Comment: I don't know what he/she want to do with it. Maybe better idea is `/(?<subdomain>.*)(?:.?)mysite\.com/`. Then in variable `subdomain` you have subdomain.

Comment: This fails with `"mysite.com"[/\.mysite\.com$/]
=> nil` and accepts `"foo.mysite.com\nbar"[/\.mysite\.com$/] =>
".mysite.com"`

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]+\.com

something.mysite.com //ok
something2.mysite.com //ok
anotherthing.mysite.com //ok
something2mysite.com //not ok
anotherthing.mysitecom //not ok
```

But It is risky because you.can.have.as.many.subdomain.as.you.want in the future

Comment: This isn't a good pattern. [(Sub)domains can contain many more characters than `[a-zA-Z0-9]`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name).

Answer (score 0):

If it just the sub domains that are changing you could use:

```
/\w+\.mysite\.com/
```

Comment: Be careful using `\w` to match a domain name. `"ае.mysite.com"[/\w+\.mysite\.com/]
=> nil`. That's a legal domain name according to [IDNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name).